# Creating a class with no init method (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to create a class with no init method so as to force all callers to create the object with a factory method instead?

Comment: It might be useful to explain what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: Seems to be a perfectly legitimate question to me, that doesn't need context to make sense.  There are plenty of reasons why you would have a class that wouldn't need any specific setup.

Comment: @Squeegy: Chuck was right - the original question should have explained what I wanted to accomplish. From the responses below it is clear some of the answerers weren't sure what I was asking (I actually upvoted Chuck's comment)

Comment: Not needing any specific setup != having no init method. All NSObject subclasses have an init method, as zneak explained.

Comment: Some classes of the Cocoa framework do not allow initialization from the `init` method. However, it does not trigger any error. NSView is such a class: you can call `init` on its instances, but it will return a non-working object.

Comment: Actually, `-[NSView init]` just calls `[view initWithFrame:NSZeroRect]`.  That's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So basically, you want to make sure that your class is never initialized using -init, right? You can't do *exactly* what you want to do, but you can come close.

Since you inherit from NSObject, you have an init method and there's nothing you can do to prevent it from being called. That said, you could override init to this:

```
- (id)init
{
   [self dealloc];
   @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"MyExceptionName" reason:@"Reason" userInfo:nil];
   return nil;
}
```

This way, anytime someone calls your -init method, it kills the object, so practically speaking, your init method is pretty much un-callable.

Comment: Does objective-c have something like a not implemented exception?

Comment: You actually don't need the return at the end - it will never be reached

Comment: Objective-C is exception-unfriendly as it can cause objects to be leaked all over the place (since their `release` calls can be never reached). If you don't use the garbage-collected runtime, however sad that may sound, you're better off simply not using them.

Comment: zneak – exceptions are used regularly for programming errors.  In a correct app, exceptions are not thrown at runtime.  This is a programming error, so it's fine.  Casebash – yes, call `[self doesNotRecognizeSelector:]`.  This is in fact the recommended way to handle this init case.  See [these docs][1].

[1] http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/doesNotRecognizeSelector:

Comment: @zneak is correct.  The Apple way to do this is to simple call [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd] and return nil.  Read the docs under NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector referred to by zneak.

Comment: Why exactly do you call `[self dealloc]` at the begin? At this point, the variable `self` is always `nil`. Or did I missed something?

Comment: @Flovdis, the expression `[[NSFoo alloc] init]` calls `init` on the object that `[NSFoo alloc]` **created**. Therefore, `-init` is merely responsible for initializing the fields of an already-existing object: `self` would be `nil` only if `+alloc` failed. The reason you usually do `self = [super init]` is that `-init` is allowed to return a different object, and in that case it would also delete the initial `self` object. If you didn't do `self = [super init]` and `[super init]` returned a different object, you'd be dealing with a dangling pointer and leak the new object.

Comment: @zneak True, meanwhile I'm so used to ARC I just forgot this simple fact. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

If you really wanted to cause trouble for users of your class who use `init`, you can do:

```
@implementation MyClass

- (id) init
{
    // Still have to make sure the runtime has initialised everything for "self"
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;
    [self release]; // some say you should use [super dealloc]
    [super doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
    return nil;
}

@end
```

You invoke `super`'s `doesNotRecognizeSelector:` because you might want to implement your own behaviour for unrecognised selectors for your class.

Comment: Why can't we just return nil?

Comment: Oh, yeh if its been allocated we should release

Comment: You can just return nil, and that's probably the better choice here.

Comment: @Chuck: do you mean to just return nil and have no `[self release]` or do you mean to have just `return nil;` as the whole method?

Comment: I meant as opposed to sending `doesNotRecognizeSelector:`, which raises an exception and thus stops the method there.

Comment: @Chuck: Just returning `nil` doesn't fit the requirements, he wants to stop people using this method. It even says in the docs for `doesNotRecognizeSelector:` to use it in `init` to prevent people calling it.

Comment: At the very least the release needs to go first. The release will never happen as is.

Comment: @dreamlax: Update - if using ARC, calling [self release] is not permitted.

Comment: Why do you actually call `[super init]`? Why not just `[super doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];` and return nil?

Answer (score 1):

Depends. If you have your class inherit from `NSObject`, it will have the inherited `init` method (which does nothing to your instance variables). So in that sense, even if you really really wanted to not have an `init` method, you'd most likely still have one. So if your question was "Do I need to implement a trivial `init` method?", the answer is "no, you don't need to". However, if your question was "Do I need to call the `init` method if I didn't override it?", then the answer is "yes, you do". Whatever you do with NSObject subclasses, at some point you still need to call `init` after the object is created. Such is the way of life.

That being said, you *most likely* want an `init` method, unless your object initialization requires nothing more than zeroing your whole object.

Otherwise, if you choose to *not* inherit from `NSObject` or any of its subclasses and just inherit from nothing, which is clearly a bad idea because of how the `NSObject` class deals with everything the ObjC runtime needs to do and the requirements are quite high, then you'll potentially end up with no `init` method *at all*. But seriously, don't try this at home.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. In Objective-C, there are no actual *constructors*. `init`-type methods are typically used to initialize a class, in the same vein as a constructor, but they're just a "normal" method (there's nothing special about them like there are with, e.g., Java constructors).

That said, unless your class does *no* initialization for its instances, you probably *want* to have some sort of `init` method.

Answer (score 0):

`NSObject` implements an `init` method for you that does whatever it does.  If your class has nothing to setup when it's instantiated then simply do not override the `-(id)init` method provided by `NSObject`.  But you still call it when you create the instance.