# Object only initialisable through factory method (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create an object only instantiatable through a factory method. I prevented `init` being used by throwing an exception (see [Creating a class with no init method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188488/creating-a-class-with-no-init-method-objective-c)). However this meant that I had to create a new method secretInit to use in the factory method.

```
//Factory method
- (URLReqs *)buildURLReq:(NSString *)location
{
    URLReqs *tmp=[[URLReqs alloc] secretInit];
    tmp.str=location
    return tmp;
}

- (id) secretInit{
    return [super init];
}
```

This method is messy and while we can avoid declaring secretInit in the header file, someone could still access it. Is there a nicer solution?

One idea is to try calling init on the super object of URLReqs directly rather than creating a function to do it.

Comment: I think your `buildURLReq:` method is supposed to return `tmp`, not `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do it this way, but it is possible:

```
#include <objc/message.h>

@implementation MyClass

+ (id) factoryMethodWithParameter:(NSString *) someString;
{
    struct objc_super instanceSuper;
    id myInstance = [self alloc];
    instanceSuper.receiver = myInstance;
    instanceSuper.super_class = [self superclass];
//  instanceSuper.class = [self superclass]; // use this line if the above doesn't compile
    myInstance = objc_msgSendSuper (&instanceSuper, @selector(init));

    //continue on setting up myInstance's ivars . . .
    [myInstance setVariable:someString];

    return myInstance;
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;
    [self release];
    [self doesNotRecogniseSelector:_cmd];
    return nil;
}

@end
```

This will allow you to continue to send `init` messages to `myInstance`'s “super” object, but won't allow anyone to send `init` to `MyClass` instances.

Be careful though, although this is using standard runtime functions declared in `objc/*.h`, don't expect Apple to keep this runtime API consistent.

Comment: Why don't I want to use this method?

Comment: I'm not sure why I told you not to use it . . .

Comment: OH! It came to me now. I was not going to recommend it because this is specific to the Apple runtime. If by some miracle `GNUstep` became bearable or alternative runtimes become available, then this method may not be usable for those runtimes. I assume you are targeting Mac OS X and/or iPhone (I'm not sure if this will work on iPhone), but since you only tagged your question `objective-c` I wanted to leave a warning. Then I forgot what I was writing about and partially finished my thought at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a category on your object to hide the secret initialization method.

[Private Methods through categories](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/private-methods.html)

What goal are you trying to accomplish? There might be a better solution than this.

Comment: This doesn't actually hide the method any more than not declaring it. It simply allows other methods within the class to know of its existence and so you don't get a compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

It only exposes it if it's referenced in the header file.

No, wait. I should state that another way. There's no better way to hide it than to not declare it in the header file. Private methods don't exist in Objective-C.